# Why does my compressor bog down at low pressure?

Tags: compressor

Just bought an air compressor, and when I turn it on it starts to build up air but when it gets to around 20 psi the motor seems to be slowing down almost to a stop. Does anyone know what's up with this?

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for a return to the store.

Comment: Yes just bought it yesterday....

Comment: Well I figured it out the compressor wasn't getting enuff power .... thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried the compressor on a different circuit (and without an extension cord)? This might point to house wiring issues. (I'm also assuming you're not in a very cold climate, as that can make compressors sluggish.)

Answer (score 2):

This is the same thing that happens when you use an extension cord of insufficient gauge to power a compressor, as you say, it's insufficient power.  Of course, it will try to pull sufficient power, and if it succeeds, probably light the extension cord on fire.